# Get JSON from website then parse it in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

So there is 1 website from where I need to get this JSON data.
The link is direct (I am using the website's API )

THe problem is, the file is HUGE!. Tens of Thousands of Lines.. Even more..

I have visual studio 2013 and what I need to do is download that JSON data in a callback and then parse it to get a specific value. I am using Newtonsoft.JSON to parse it and here is what I have thought will be able to parse it

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JContainer>(jsonText);
var value = (int)obj["response"]["prices"]["5021"]["6"]["0"]["current"]["value"];
```

The problem is, how do I download all of that data and convert it into C# classes? Is there another way?
Thanks a lot.

EDIT: If not JSON, I have option to download it in JSONP and VDF format

Here is the link of the JSON data - http://backpack.tf/api/IGetPrices/v3/?format=json&key=52f75dab4dd7b82f698b4568

Comment: I'm not convinced you should be sharing that key on the internet for everyone to see?

Comment: I don't think it is a problem.. I can anytime revoke it and get a new one

Comment: K, SO isn't letting me answer your question so... here: your thread is a duplicate of this resolved thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749639/deserializing-json-to-net-object-using-newtonsoft-or-linq-to-json-maybe

Comment: Also this responds with the error message *You can only request this page once per minute per API key. Try again in 46 seconds.*....

Comment: Liam, I belive you can understand what it means.. Try again later.. It can be accessed by someone only once per minute

Comment: Have you heard of the JavascriptSerializer?

Comment: No, not really. I don't have much experience in C#

Comment: @LukeAlderton What does it do better than Json.Net?

Comment: What's the actual question here? That file isn't huge by any strech. *What exactly are you having trouble with?* Json.Net is probably your best tool for this kind of work. even Micorsoft recommend it these days ahead of their (fundamentally flawed Javascriptserializer)

Comment: @Liam - How do I download it and parse the specific data I need.. I need this part  ["response"]["prices"]["5021"]["6"]["0"]["current"]["value"];

Comment: Um guys.. Thank you for your help and helping me with the basic data. @Brandon - I figured it out after reading a couple more questions. I have edited my main post with the answer included since I cannot post answer before 8 hours

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by doing this

```
using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            var json = webClient.DownloadString("http://backpack.tf/api/IGetPrices/v3/?format=json&key=00a00aaa0aa0a00a000a0000");
            Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject o = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json);
            var value = (int)o["response"]["prices"]["5021"]["6"]["0"]["current"]["value"];
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
```

Thanks for your help everybody!!

Answer (score 0):

Try [restsharp](http://restsharp.org/). It let you do something like

```
var prices = client.Execute<Prices>(request);
```

Where Prices is the class that matches the returned schema

Comment: why the vote down? he asked how he can load it into c# classes.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the comment Brandon posted, he's right in principle, but you don't have to switch to Newtonsoft if you don't want. You just need to use a different JSON.NET API

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
using (var stream = File.OpenRead("C:\\Users\\gweakliem\\Downloads\\sotest.js"))
{
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        using (JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
        {
            var aThing = serializer.Deserialize<JContainer>(reader);
            var aValue = (int) aThing["response"]["prices"]["5021"]["6"]["0"]["current"]["value"];
            Console.WriteLine("Read a value " + aValue);
        }
    }
}
```

If you're concerned about blocking on this thread while reading, it looks like you're going to have to write some code. I don't see awaitable methods on JsonTextReader or JsonSerializer, so I expect that those methods will block.

Now if you want to turn this into objects, here's a couple other SO posts:

- [deserialize json into .net object using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17858046/deserialize-json-into-net-object-using-json-net)
- [dynamic JContainer (JSON.NET) & Iterate over properties at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652983/dynamic-jcontainer-json-net-iterate-over-properties-at-runtime)

Or [this post](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Aug/30/Using-JSONNET-for-dynamic-JSON-parsing) covers a bunch of deserialization options.

Comment: i fixed it.. i edited my main post.. i cannot answer myself before 8 hours though